# Visual Studio 2012 Entity Framework don't have MySQL Data Source Type

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I'm using visual studio 2012 and installed MySQL 5.7 and all the developer tools. After I added EF 6.0 etc from Nuget and try to link to my database, MySQL is not part of the available data source as depicted below.

[image]

I can however, see the selection when trying to add connection at Server Explorer. May I know if anybody knows how to fix it? What have I missed? Thank you.

Update 1:
These are what I have installed.
[image]

Comment: VS only SQL Server is available. But you can create manually at your own.

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM8WmrMeQ7o This example is able to do it

Comment: Then if you can find any other newly application to do it then it could be better. What im saying is it is a default for VS.

Comment: Eventually, we did it last few days ago and its working using mysql connection working with MVC5

Comment: you need to [install the DDEX provider](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)

Comment: I have installed that, in fact, I have installed everything that recommended. Strange thing is, it works in my VM which also running VS2012. Not sure why it ain't working in my local PC.

Answer (score 1):

After trying with my local PC and my VM, I found out the problem. Since I installed mysql-connector-net-6.10.5.msi, it's not supported. At my VM I had installed the mysql-connector-net-6.9.10.msi instead.

After changing the local PC to mysql-connector-net-6.9.10.msi, I'm able to see the data source. Is MySQL trying to phase out the support in the future?

Comment: looks like last version dropped VS2012 support. this happens other time that older VS version no longer get supported